How to load records of csv file in snowflake?
id,title,year,text
1,t1,1998,"abcd"
2,c\,1999,"abcdef"
3,d,1989,"xyz"

These are my contents in csv file. I want to load them in snowflake. I tried various approach like setting  like below :
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT double_slash_q1
TYPE = 'CSV'
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE
ESCAPE = '\\'
SKIP_HEADER = 1
TRIM_SPACE = TRUE;

but they don't work. Let me know what can be the solution?

Hi - what does “they don’t work “ actually mean? What’s the error message, etc? Also, please update your question with your COOY INTO statement or whatever it is you are using to actually load the data
